# ASP.NET mvc validation label on dropdownlist with integer value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I have an issue with displaying the right validation label for an integer field.

Here is my model properties:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the title.")]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country.")]
public int RegionId { get; set; }
```

Here is my cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.article.Title, new { @placeholder = "Title", @autofocus = true })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.article.Title)


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("RegionControl")
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DataValueField("RegionId")
                .OptionLabel("Select one...")
                .Events(e => e.Change("RegionChange").DataBound("RegionDataBound"))
                .BindTo(Model.regions)
                .Value(Model.article.RegionId.ToString())
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.article.RegionId)
```

My problem is that the validation message for Title is displaying fine `("Please enter the title.")`, BUT the validation for the dropdownlist is the default one `("The value 'NaN' is not valid for RegionId.")`.

Why is the validation message for RegionId not displaying the message I set in the model `("Please select a country.")`? Is it due to the default value `(OptionLabel)`? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to remove the `html.dropdownlistfor` tag and add a `Kendo` tag to this question

Comment: Why do you have a hidden input for the property as welll?

Comment: yes, sorry you are right @StephenMuecke, you can ignore the hiddenfor. (answer edited)

Comment: @markpsmith absolutely, thanks for the edit!

Comment: no one has an idea on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your RegionId property as `nullable`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country.")]
public int? RegionId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @nevra, thanks for you answer but that doesn't solve my issue :-(

Comment: This worked for me in .NET Core 2 MVC and Telerik UI for AspNet.Core 2018.3.1017.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`[Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Please select a country.")]`

Assuming the default dropdown item has an ID of zero, and none of your regions has an ID of zero, this should work.